# SQL Server- duplicates from TRANSACTION with SELECT / INSERT on 'unique' value existing

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I am really new to SQL Transaction management, and I have been reading up a lot on transaction management, specifically concurrency issues and isolation levels.

I have a rather 'simple' problem that I can't seem to solve-

The database has a table of consumers with a primary key, ConsumerID, and an indexed (but not unique) field that should be unique, SSN.  We have a stored procedure to handle incoming loan requests that essentially has this block of code to maintain the Consumer table:

```
    SELECT @ConsumerID = ConsumerID FROM Consumer WHERE SSN = @SSN
    IF @ConsumerID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Consumer (SSN, ...) VALUES (@SSN, ...)
        SELECT @ConsumerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
```

We have been getting instances where two requests to the stored procedure come in simultaneously, and (of course) we are getting duplicate SSN records in the Consumer table.  Making the SSN index UNIQUE is on the table, but not something we can do right now.  The solution was to use a TRANSACTION:

```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT @ConsumerID = ConsumerID FROM Consumer WHERE SSN = @SSN
        IF @ConsumerID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO Consumer (SSN, ...) VALUES (@SSN, ...)
            SELECT @ConsumerID = @SCOPE_IDENTITY
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
```

Now, this certainly prevents duplicate SSNs, because of the TRANSACTION. However, I did a concurrency test by calling the stored procedure asynchronously many times from two C# processes running at the same time.  The performance is affected by the TRANSACTION on the order of several seconds.  This is not acceptable since we rely on speed as the primary factor of our system responses.

How can I tweak this TRANSACTION to improve response time?  I have a hunch it lies somewhere in optimistic concurrency (we use the default for SQL Server), but I don't understand how it works in relation to such a pair of SELECT - INSERT instructions.  Remember, making the SSN index UNIQUE is a possibility, but one we may not wish to pursue right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of exclusive locks to make sure other users cannot insert duplicates while you are querying and inserting values by doing something like......

```
BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Consumer WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK) WHERE SSN = @SSN)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Consumer (SSN, ...) VALUES (@SSN, ...)
        SELECT @ConsumerID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    END
  COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 IF (@@TRANCOUNT <> 0)
     ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can test with SQL Insert Trigger for the table and rollback the transaction that will cause the duplicate values in the table. Compare the time taken for it.
2. In case the above option is not possible. Minimize the work inside inside the transaction, if that is not possible then optimize the query for SELECT & INSERT or any other query inside the transaction.

The query execution time will depends upon the number of index exists on the tables, number of records in the table. INSERT are faster with no or minimum Indexes, while SELECT may benefit well with it. Take a look at the Query execution plan.

```
create table test(id int)
Go

Create TRIGGER test_insert_one  
ON test  
AFTER INSERT
AS 
Declare @Count int
select @Count = count(id) from test where id = (select id from inserted)
IF(@Count > 1)
    Rollback;
GO  

insert into test
select 1
GO
insert into test
select 1
GO

select * from test
GO
```